# USB device gets hot when plugged into Samsung Chromebook

Tags: laptop, usb, usb-flash-drive

I just recently noticed that USB devices that I plug into my Samsung XE303C12 get pretty warm after being connected for a few minutes. I noticed this first (I think) with a very small SanDisk USB 3.0 drive that has a metal casing. It's small enough that the casing and the metal cover over the USB connector are the same piece. This is after plugging it into the USB 3.0 port. I also checked this with another USB 3.0 drive and it also gets hot. I did with the USB 2.0 port and a stripped USB 2.0 drive and got the same result; the USB drive's microcontroller was hot. Is this normal with USB drives?

Answer (score 2):

USB 3.0 interface has to process data stream at 5 Gbps rate. It requires a digital electronics working at very high frequency, 5 GHz at least. A digital processor working at 5 GHz requires some power to run, and it makes USB 3.0 bridges (USB to SATA and USB to eMMC) get hot. Some ICs would consume up to 0.5 -1 W of power depending on which manufacturing node (130nm, 65nm, 45nm, etc.) the manufacturer can afford, and they will run hot, especially in small-size enclosures. This is normal, and should get better with overall progress in silicon manufacturing.

The other thing that can make a difference in power dissipation of a USB 3.0 device is whether the host system (and device) enables and maintains hardware-level Link Power Management on this particular USB 3.0 link. Historically there were challenges in enabling USB 3.0 link power management, so not all controllers might have this feature enabled.

Comment: Hot enough to feel like it is going to burn my skin?